# Populating QTreeview with item C++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm driving myself crazy here. How can i populate a QTreeView in C++ using QtCreator with some simple data like so? I'm new to this, i have a background in C# and wpf. Thanks for the help and sorry for the basic question, however I haven't found a solution online showing a simple example. All the examples show Files and Folders which is NOT what I'm doing.

```
Sports
|____ Soccer
|____ Basketball
|____ Football
|____ Tennis
Teams
|____ Cowboys
|____ Packers
|____ Lions
|____ Tennessee
Players
|____ Ronald
|____ Warner
|____ Robinson
```

This is my **mainwindow.h** file

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: You would do it the same way as the examples showing files and folders. For example, "Sports" is the folder with "Soccer", "Basketball", "Football", and "Tennis" files. Even though you're not showing files and folders the code to structure the items is the same.

Comment: Nitpicks: You don't need to include `<QtGui>`, `<QtCore>` and `QMainWindow`. Include `<QtWidgets>`, that's sufficient. You can also include the `"ui_mainwindow.h"`, and then hold `ui` by value, not by pointer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTreeView` needs your model class to be used. Try to use [QTreeWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html) which can work with `QString` and icons etc. Try put the snippet into constructor of main widget. It shows the top level item with one subitem and one additional column. If you know all the items at design time you add them in the the Qt Designer.

```
auto w = new QTreeWidget;
w->setColumnCount(2);
auto t = new QTreeWidgetItem(QStringList() << "Top" << "Col2 a");
auto i = new QTreeWidgetItem(QStringList() << "Some" << "Col2 b");
t->addChild(i);
w->addTopLevelItem(t);
w->show();
```